# plugin:elasticsearch service not available in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, sense

In order to use sense plugin, I have some problems when integrating kibana with elastic search. Everyting goes well. Elastic search and kibana installed properly in my machine.

When I run this command :
`cd elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch.bat`
and then I go to `http://localhost:9200/`,
I got success message.

When I run this command :
`cd kibana/bin/kibana.bat`
and then I go to `http://localhost:5601/app/sense`
I got notification that

> plugin:elasticsearch is not available.

[image]

this is prove that my elastic already running
[image]

[image]

this is my kibana.yml
[image]

this is my elastic.yml
[image]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your elasticsearch process is running? It doesn't look like it is.

Comment: In the second image, the IP mentioned is 192.168.1.104 which doesn't look to be localhost. Please mention this IP in kibana.yml to connect with Elasticsearch.

Comment: @YuvrajGupta what do you mean dude? i dont hv this 192.168.1.104 ip address....

Comment: Are you facing this issue only when you have installed Sense? Maybe just try uninstalling Sense Plugin and checking whether ES & Kibana are running or not.